# EC2 instance has stopped assigning public ips

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance that I use to run a minecraft server. It's been working fine for months now, but recently it has stopped auto assigning a public ip address on launch. The vpc and the subnet are all set up correctly and it used to assign those ips fine.

**Edit for Clarity:**  We start and stop the instance as we use it, sshing into the instance to start the minecraft server. Up until now that process has worked. Now when we start the stopped server it will start, just not auto assign a public ip. I tried assigning an elastic ip but when we ssh'd into the server the minecraft files were gone. I tried starting and stopping the server again multiple time & toggling the vpc & subnet settings but no dice. I launched a new instance from an image of the old one and that starts with the auto public ip so the setup works but again no minecraft files.

So multipart question:

- Do EC2 instances just stop assigning public ips if they are started/stopped too often?
- Is this fixable?
- Are my files gone? If yes are they retrievable?

Comment: Are you launching a new server or starting a stopped server? Your question is not clear. Be as descriptive as possible.